# How to calculate html input box values in another input box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Following table is accessing values from mysql table in first two columns (exclude sr.no.) and offering to enter 'obtained marks' in 4th column. I have also made three columns after obtained marks which are 'percentage', 'grade' and remarks. I want to calculate percentage automatically when user enters marks in obtained marks column and navigates to next input box which is in second row:

```
<table id = "result" class="data-table">

        <caption class="title"></caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>    
                <th><strong>Sr.No.</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Student ID</strong></th>
                <th align="center"><strong>Student Name</strong></th>
                <th style="text-align: center;"><strong>Obtained Marks</strong></th>
                <th style="text-align: center;"><strong>Percentage</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;"><strong>Grade</strong></th>
                <th style="text-align: center;"><strong>Remarks</strong></th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        $no     = 1;
        $total  = 0;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $stu  = $row['stu_id'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['stu_id']);
            echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$no.'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['student_id'].'</td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="student_id[]" value='.$row['student_id'].'>
                    <td style="text-align: left;">'.$row['student_name'].'</td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="student_name[]" value='.$row['student_name'].'>
                    <td>'."<input name='obtmarks[]' placeholder='' class='form-control'  type='number' required='required' style='width: 120px;'>".'</td>
                    <td>'."<input name='percentage[]' placeholder='' class='form-control'  type='number' required='required' style='width: 120px;'>".'</td>
                    <td>'."<input name='grade[]' placeholder='' class='form-control'  type='number' required='required' style='width: 120px;'>".'</td>
                    <td>'."<input name='remarks[]' placeholder='' class='form-control'  type='number' required='required' style='width: 120px;'>".'</td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="class[]" value='.$row['class'].'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="test_date[]" value='.$test_Date.'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="test_subject[]" value='.$Subject_type.'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="test_type[]" value='.$TestType.'>

                </tr>';

            $total += $row['stu_id'];
            $no++;

        }

        ?>
</tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: What does percentage represent ?

Comment: it will be the result of a formula (obtained_marks/total_marks)*100.

Comment: You could make it with Jquery and calculate on input change (or keyup)

Comment: @JulesR Can you please write some code for me..I will be highly obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply achieve this by using `<input type="text"/>` event of `onkeyup('calculateFn()')`. For this, you have Total Marks too to get that percentage out for your obtained marks.
using this script

```
<script>
    var obmarks=document.getElementById("obmarks");
    var totalmarks=document.getElementById("totalmarks");
    var percent=(obmarks/totalmarks)*100;
    document.getElementById("percentage").value=percent;
</script>
```

here ids are those corresponding ids of required text fields.
Hope this help you out.